# MySQL SELECT to Rank A Number out of a set of numbers

Tags: mysql, select, case, rank

I have rows of data from a SELECT query with a few prices (say three for this example).  One is our price, one is competitor1 price, one is competitor2 price.  I want to add a column that spits out the rank of our price as compared to the other two prices; if our price is the lowest it would spit out the number 1 if the highest it would spit out the number it is out of.

Something like this:

```
Make |  Model  |  OurPrice | Comp1Price  | Comp2Price | Rank |  OutOf
MFG1    MODEL1     350         100           500         2        3
MFG1    MODEL2     50          100           100         1        3
MFG2    MODEL1     100         NULL          50          2        2
MFG2    MODEL2     9999        500           NULL        2        2
```

-Sometimes the competitor price will be NULL as seen above, and I believe this is where my issue lies.  I have tried a `CASE` and it works when only on one competitor but when I add a `AND` statement it spits out the ranks as all `NULL`.  Is there a better way of doing this through a MySQL query?

```
SELECT
      MT.MAKE as Make,
      MT.MODEL as Model,
      MT.PRICE as OurPrice,
      CT1.PRICE as Comp1Price,
      CT2.PRICE as Comp2Price,
      CASE
         WHEN MT.PRICE < CT1.PRICE AND MT.PRICE < CT2.PRICE
         THEN 1 END AS Rank
      (CT1.PRICE IS NOT NULL) + (CT2.PRICE IS NOT NULL) + 1 as OutOf
  FROM mytable MT

LEFT JOIN competitor1table as CT1 ON CT1.MODEL = MT.MODEL
LEFT JOIN competitor2table as CT2 ON CT2.MODEL = MT.MODEL

ORDER BY CLASS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested, but you can try:

```
SELECT
    a.MAKE AS Make,
    a.MODEL AS Model,
    a.PRICE AS OurPrice
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.compnum = 1 THEN pricelist END) AS Comp1Price,
    MAX(CASE WHEN a.compnum = 2 THEN pricelist END) AS Comp2Price,
    FIND_IN_SET(a.PRICE, GROUP_CONCAT(a.pricelist ORDER BY a.pricelist)) AS Rank,
    COUNT(a.pricelist) AS OutOf
FROM
(
    SELECT MAKE, MODEL, PRICE, PRICE AS pricelist, 0 AS compnum
    FROM mytable

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.MAKE, a.MODEL, a.PRICE, CT1.PRICE, 1
    FROM mytable a
    LEFT JOIN competitor1table CT1 ON a.MODEL = CT1.MODEL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.MAKE, a.MODEL, a.PRICE, CT2.PRICE, 2
    FROM mytable a
    LEFT JOIN competitor2table CT2 ON a.MODEL = CT2.MODEL
) a
GROUP BY
    a.MAKE, a.MODEL
```

Comment: It kind of works for two competitors, however, I need to add a WHERE statement on the mytable along with a COST and MARGIN field.  Moreso, in its current form it seems like it doubles some model numbers (they appear twice), they should only appear once on one row.

Comment: @ToddN How many competitor tables do you have? Also, in your sample result-set, you also have model numbers appearing twice (but for different `MAKE`s), so then how are the rows to be grouped?

Answer (score 0):

```
(CT1.PRICE IS NOT NULL AND CT1.PRICE < MT.PRICE) + (CT2.PRICE IS NOT NULL AND CT2.PRICE < MT.PRICE) + 1 as Rank
```